# sequence of lebesgue measurable function

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose that $f_n:[0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ is a sequence of Lebesgue measurable function on [0,1]. Prove that

$A = \{x\in[0,1]|f_n \text{ convergent} \}$
is a measurable set.

Does this means that $f_n$ converges to an function $f$? If so, then A is measurable since a sequence of measurable function converge to a measurable function, thus A need to be measurable. I really don't understand this problem well. Please help

Comment: Consider $\liminf_n f_n$ and $\limsup_n f_n$

Comment: For each $x$, the sequence $f_1(x),f_2(x),f_3(x),\dots$ is a sequence of numbers, and it either converges or it does not. Letting $A$ be the set of $x$ for which that sequence converges, you need to show $A$ is measurable. Tim's comment is helpful; you can show $A=g^{-1}(B)$, for a certain measurable function $g$ and a certain measurable set $B$.

Comment: $f_n(x)$ may converge for some $x$ and not for others.  The set $A$ is those points $x$ such that $f_n(x)$ converges.